# remove cycle for a BGL graph

Tags: boost, graph, cycle

I want to remove cycles in a BGL graph (BGL adjacency_list) , and I found some people have suggested to use depth_first_search method that accepts a visitor like this

```
class CycleTerminator : public boost::dfs_visitor<> {
template <class Edge, class Graph>
void back_edge(Edge e, Graph& g) {
    //implement
}
};
```

but I doubt whether I can use depth_first_search to remove edges in a graph, because depth_first_search has a const graph parameter, so it can not remove edges, I am looking forward to get an answer. Thank you very much.